# While looping not ending at null character

Tags: c

I have a loop in a C language code:

```
i = 0;

while(!isdigit(password[i]) && password[i++] != '\0');
```

password is declared globally like this:

```
char password[33];
```

`i` is an integer.

I want to check if the password a user is entering has at least one number or not.

If I replaced '\0' with any other character, say, 'p', it works iff p appears in the middle of the character array,

ex:

1.It works if:

```
password = bblahblah9**pa**
```

2.It doesn't work if:

```
password = blahblah9**p**
```

I guess, it is not scanning the end of the string correctly as the null character is always at the end it is being, I don't know, skipped or something.

Comment: scanf("%s", password);

Comment: You should change `isdigit(password[i])` to `isdigit((unsigned char)password[i])` because `isdigit` doesn't handle negative inputs and `char` can be a signed type.

Comment: It is still an infinite loop @melpomene

Comment: @AkshayAnurag Yes, your code has more than one bug. That's why it's just a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't contain a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) nor a problem description.

Comment: @melpomene but I have used the same logic at one other point in my code. Its with checking another string for null character and it takes input from a file using fscanf() and it works correctly but the "password" string takes input from the user using scanf() and it messes with the null character.

Comment: It cannot work differently with `bblahblah9pa` and `blahblah9p`. In both cases the loop is interrupted once `'9'` is found.

Comment: Is it possible that you increment `i` twice in your original loop, for example, `while(!isdigit(password[i]) && password[i++] != '\0') i++` ?

Comment: No. They are two different examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The index `i` is not incremented once you find a digit:

```
!isdigit(password[i]) && password[i++] != '\0'
```

if `isdigit(password[i])` returns `true` the right side of `&&` operator is not evaluated.

Comment: while(!isdigit(password[i]) && password[i] != '\0')  i++;

Comment: @Akshay Anurag, No, the loop is interrupted on the first digit.

Comment: @OrestHera  Why  would loop be interrupted ?

Comment: `!isdigit(password[i]) && password[i++] != '\0'` is `false` on the first digit. So, the loop is interrupted due to `while (false)`.

Comment: because it is (not) of isdigit()

Comment: That's very much my problem. If my user enters a password with a digit it works fine, that is the digit checker is working fine but when there is no digit the loop doesn't terminates that means it is unable to find a null character at the end of the password string which means that there is something wrong with the end of that string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#include <usual.h>

int checknoint( char *pass )
{
 int i = 0;

 for( i = 0; pass[i] != '\0'; i++)
 {
 if ( isdigit( pass[i] ) )
  return ( 1 );
}
return ( 0 );
}

int main()
{
char password[50];

//strcpy( password , "atestwith no number");
strcpy( password , "atestwith a9 number");

if( !checknoint(password)) printf("\n ok");
else    printf("\n NOT ok");

}
```

Comment: Your loop logic is flawed: the initial character is always skipped.  Why not use the standard C idiom:  `for (int i = 0; pass[i] != '\0'; i++) { ... }`